# javascript maximum number of elements in an array....browser not allowing more than 1000 elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, max

I am trying to add around 5000 elements to a JavaScript array. But seems the browsers are not happy with this. In chrome, I get this error message in Firefox's console:

> SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

And this seems to indicate that ] is required after the 1000th element in the array...

Sample codes:

```
var uid=["a1","a2","a3"..."a5000"];
```

any idea how to get around this?

Comment: There is no such limit.

Comment: Modern browsers easily support arrays of that size (just try using `new Array(5000)`), your error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: `uid[5000] = 'five thousands';` works fine....

Comment: Sounds like bad data to me.

Comment: SyntaxError is a...surprise...syntax problem . it doesn't have to do with runtime conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a quotation mark on one or more of your elements.

In Firefox:

```
var a = ['a', 'b, 'c'] // SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
```

Comment: Indeed...due to the super-lengthy array, some elements had quotes at the wrong location...my bad!